# Delete SharePoint Recyclebin using powershell and webservices

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

can some one help me out on how to Delete SharePoint 2007 /2010 Recyclebin using powershell and webservices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can empty web's recycle bin using this two lines in powershell:

```
$w = get-spweb http://localhost
$w.RecycleBin.DeleteAll()
```

But I never combined powershell and web services, so this maybe not what you asked for.